# How to make colorpicker in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, color-picker

Is it possible to use the windows color picker in IE? I haven't found anything. I hope, I can do some magic with activex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use JQuery Color Picker plugin. Right here http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Comment: I don't want to use libraries.

Comment: I wrote, that I want to use activex

Comment: I hope it is not too late to welcome you in the future, Danny Fox.